# missing key i18next message but it's working

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, i18next

I keep getting this message

```
i18next::translator: missingKey es-AR translation El campo Ciudad es obligatorio. El campo Ciudad es obligatorio.
am-trips-my-trips.module.js:5 i18next::translator: missingKey es-AR translation El campo Ciudad es obligatorio. El campo Ciudad es obligatorio.
```

The text is shown the the user try to submit with blank inputs that are required.

> event-form.component.js

```
  get originRequired(){
                return this.$i18next.t('event-form.' + this.event.type + '.originRequired', {originLabel: this.originLabel})
            }
```

> event-form.json

```
{
    "event-form": {
        "hotel": {
            "originRequired": "El campo {{originLabel}} es obligatorio.",
        }
}
```

Should I translate it like this? don't want it to pass it as a default value!!. I want to pass it as a key!
Altough it's working, it's because is the default value but I want to pass it as a key with the interpolation. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not really understanding your question. Made a small jsfiddle:

```
i18next.init({
  lng: 'en',
  resources: {
     en: {
       translation: {
         "event-form": {
           "hotel": {
             "originRequired": "El campo {{originLabel}} es obligatorio.",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, function(err, t) {
  // initialized and ready to go!
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = i18next.t('event-form.hotel.originRequired', { originLabel: 'Ciudad' });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jamuhl/8339motk/

There is no missing if the key exists. You get a missing cause it is missing.

What you mean by: don't want it to pass it as a default value!!. I want to pass it as a key!

Comment: This messages are shown when the user submit's the form and leaves blank inputs.
They appear like a warning

Comment: The translation it's working! But no on init. because that text it's not being shown

Comment: Than it looks like angular renders before i18next loaded the resources - moving angular bootstrapping to the i18next.init callback should solve it